# Is there a way to see all resources sending logs to a log analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-log-analytics

I know that I can go to "Azure Resources" to view the resources that are connected, but it doesn't list everything that I have set to point to the workspace. For instance, CDN endpoints don't have a setting that you can configure in the portal, but you can do it in powershell. They're not listed on the Azure Resources blade in the workspace, either. I have tried using the query

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| summarize count() by Category
```

This only showed three categories. For nsgs and a key vault. I have a lot more resources connected to this workspace.

Answer (score 0):

we can enable CDN diagnostics logging with Azure PowerShell / Portal as well. For detailed instructions, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-azure-diagnostic-logs) tutorial.

As mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-logs-schema) tutorial, CDN falls under the list of services that support AzureDiagnostics table logs (with the supported log category of 'CoreAnalytics' which helps to get the CDN endpoint metrics bandwidth, egress, etc.)

AFAIK the reason for not getting CDN related logs under your AzureDiagnostics table would be because the configuration of CDN to send diagnostic logs to Log Analytics was not done properly or else the CDN service hasn't generated any new log for some reason.

I would suggest you to (double check or) enable CDN diagnostics logging with Azure PowerShell / Portal as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-azure-diagnostic-logs) and see if it resolves the issue.

Hope this helps!!